# How to dismiss bluetooth picker displayed by EAAccessoryManager

Tags: ios, bluetooth, picker, eaaccessory

when I call

```
[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter:predicate completion:^(NSError *error) {}];
```

my app displays a bluetooth picker and it works fine. But how to dismiss it programatically ?

I tried to display system view such as Message, Mail Camera or even alert views, hopping this will hide the bluetooth picker but none of this worked...

Thanks in advance !